# Export all objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

A node.js module of mine got too big, so I split it into several smaller (sub)modules.

I copy & pasted all relevant objects into each of the submodules, which now look like

```
var SOME_CONSTANT = 10;

function my_func() { etc... };
```

Now I want to export everything in each submodule, en masse, without having to explicitly say `exports.SOME_CONSTANT = SOME_CONSTANT` a million times (I find that both ugly and error prone).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not want to export every local variable.

I will get around to automating this one of these days, but for now I often use this  technique.

```
 var x1 = { shouldExport: true  } ;
```

// create a macro in your favorite editor to search and replace so that

```
x1.name = value ; // instead of var name  = value
```

and

```
name becomes x1.name
```

// main body of module

```
for ( var i in x1) { exports.better_longer_name[i]   = x1[i] ;} 
//or if you want to add all directly to the export scope  
for ( var i in x1) {  exports[i] = x1[i] ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    SOME_CONSTANT_0 : SOME_CONSTANT_1 ,
    SOME_CONSTANT_1 : SOME_CONSTANT_2 ,
    SOME_CONSTANT_2 : SOME_CONSTANT_3
}
```

so why you need that "million" constant to exports?

Comment: Because this duplicates code (DRY, inviting errors), plus is ugly. I'd prefer an automated solution that I could copy&paste into each submodule.

Comment: I think you need some trick to rebuild your code, e.g. replace = to : and ; to ,